# How can i automate DIfferential restore using dbatools Powershell

Tags: powershell

How can i automate DIfferential restore using dbatools Powershell

I have configured FUllbackup migration from powershell using dbatools and using multi thread I am able to restore 4.5TB under 4 hours.

As for the downtime I want to also automate the Differential Restore using powershell.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what you've come up with so far?

In the [Restore-DbaDatabase](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Restore-DbaDatabase) you can use -IgnoreDiffBackup to ignore the differential backups, so I presume there should be no problem with automating your diffs.

Can you add more details what you are trying to achieve and how your backup process looks like?